# using MySqlBulkCopy of MySqlConnector to upload a datatable into MySql. Exception thrown

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

Well i switched to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) in order to be able to use its functionality to upload a Datatable into a MySql Table.
I'm following their simple [example](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysql-bulk-copy/) for this function as follow :

```
  DataTable datatable = Globals.ds.Tables["Song"];

        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(Globals.connString + "AllowLoadLocalInfile = true;"))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Song2";
            await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(datatable);
        }
```

The Song2 table is a empty copy of the Song table that contains 17000 lines and that is feeding the Datatable through a `adapter.fill()` method (i even did a `.FillSchema()` before).
When i run this, i have 2 exceptions :
The first one (the `innerexception`) is `Failed to read the result set.` while the second one is `"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException"`

Anyone can help ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT :
Here is the call stack

```
  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  HResult=0x80131604
  Message=Une exception a été levée par la cible d'un appel.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at MP3_manager.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Utilisateur\source\repos\MP3-manager\MP3-manager\Program.cs:line 23

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    MySqlConnector.Utilities.SocketAwaitable.GetResult() in SocketAwaitable.cs
    MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.SocketByteHandler.DoWriteBytesAsync(System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>) in SocketByteHandler.cs
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.ProtocolUtility.WritePacketAsync.__WritePacketAsyncAwaited|8_0(System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<int>, byte[]) in ProtocolUtility.cs
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.SendReplyAsyncAwaited(System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<int>) in ServerSession.cs
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]

Inner Exception 1:
MySqlException: Failed to read the result set.

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
```

Comment: Your exception sounds similar to https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/780
Can you paste the full call stack here, or comment on that issue?

Comment: Are you copying between two tables on the same database server, or copying between servers? If they're on the same server, it would probably be a lot more efficient to do `INSERT INTO Song2 SELECT * FROM Song;` and do the copy completely on the server. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Hi Bradley, my goal is not to copy between 2 databases, i'm testing it this way for simplicity but eventually, a routine is building the dataset and then, that dataset is loaded into the Database. this loading mechanism is taking 30 mn on 17000 records (the adapter.fill() )

Comment: Thanks Bradley, fro my comment on the issue, the Dataset is "only" 17 000 lines but has 25 columns. It's 12 mb. It's basically a list of MP3 files that are sitting on a drive with taglib information for each. The index is the path of each file and by the way, the "MySqlBulkLoader " method that you helped me with yesterday, i realize all the backslashs that are in the path are present in the txt file but disappear during the MySqlBulkLoader process. Do you know why ?

Comment: `MySqlBulkLoader` eventually turns into `LOAD DATA` on the MySQL Server. See the documentation for `ESCAPED BY` at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html. The default escape character is `\` so it will be treated as the beginning of an escape sequence. The fixes would be: a) escape all backslashes in your input data (by doubling them); b) set `MySqlBulkLoader.EscapeCharacter` to a different character (that you don't use in your data). If `MySqlBulkCopy` were working, it would avoid this problem by handling the string escaping itself.

Comment: Again thanks Bradley. So i went back to MySqlBulkLoader because i wasnt able to fix the above issue. And strangely, i have the following issue with MySqlConnector : 'Failed to read the result set.' , line 60 of MySqlBulkLoader.cs. If  i switch to MySql.Data, it works. One other issue i have, the EscapeCharacter worked (thanks !!) but strangely enough, that same field, the path for the file get truncated with a max of 53 char (i think), knowing that in the csv, the path is complete ... Would you know why ? (the field in MySql is 255 long)

Comment: please disregard the truncate issue, it's solved.